# Return the last word of a string - C programming

Tags: c, string, pointers

The task is to create a function which will return the last word of a string. For example in a string

```
Danas je divan dan!
```

the function should return  `dan`, without the `!`.
Another example is

```
Danas  je divan   dan
```

where the function should again return `dan`, but it has to ignore all of the spaces after that word.

Here is what I have come up with so far :

```
#include <stdio.h>

char *PosljednjaRijec(char *s) {
    char *p = s;
    while (*p != '\0')
        p++;
    while (*p != ' ')
        p--;
    p++;

    return p;
}

int main() {
    printf("Posljednja rijec: %s", PosljednjaRijec("Danas je divan dan!\n"));
    printf("Posljednja rijec: %s", PosljednjaRijec("  Danas  je divan   dan   "));
    return 0;
}
```

My question is how to return the last word, without anything behind her such as whitespaces or other signs? I'm having problems with ignoring everything after the last word.

Comment: Please read [ask]. You forgot to include a question.

Answer (score 3):

If you are allowed to modify the array, just set a `'\0'` terminator after the last word found. If not, you need to allocate memory and return a copy of the last word, to be later freed with `free()`.

Note that in your `main` function, you pass string constants to the `PosljednjaRijec` function, so it should not modify the array pointed to by its argument, declaring it as `const char *s` would make this more explicit. Hence only the second option is safe and since you do not free the return value, you have memory leaks.

Note also that your current implementation has undefined behavior if the argument array does not contain any spaces.

Here is a solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char *PosljednjaRijec(const char *s) {
    int i, j = strlen(s);
    while (j > 0 && s[j - 1] == ' ')
        j--;
    for (i = j; i > 0 && s[i - 1] != ' '; i--)
        continue;
    char *p = malloc(j - i + 1);
    if (p) {
        memcpy(p, s + i, j - i);
        p[j - i] = '\0';
    }
    return p;
}
```

**EDIT:** with your extra requirements, you could modify the function to return a pointer to the first character of the last word, along with an `int` stating the number of characters in the last word. You probably want to skip all white space characters, which is easy to do with `isspace()` defined in `<ctype.h>`:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char *PosljednjaRijec(const char *s, int *plen) {
    int i, j = strlen(s);
    while (j > 0 && isspace((unsigned char)s[j - 1]))
        j--;
    for (i = j; i > 0 && !isspace((unsigned char)s[i - 1]); i--)
        continue;
    *plen = j - i;
    return (char *)(s + i);
}

int main() {
    int len;
    char *p;
    p = PosljednjaRijec("Danas je divan dan!\n", &len);
    printf("Posljednja rijec: '%.*s'\n", len, p);
    p = PosljednjaRijec("  Danas  je divan   dan   ", &len);
    printf("Posljednja rijec: '%.*s'\n", len, p);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Posljednja rijec: 'dan!'
Posljednja rijec: 'dan'
```

Comment: @interjay: correct. Already modified the answer to this regard.

Comment: In my assignment it says that the function should not modify the original string, just return a pointer, that points at the beginning of the last word. It also says we can't use memory allocation.

Comment: @KenanHatibović then what is asked for is not possible.  One pointer alone cannot define the extent of a word.  Either a char is chosen as a terminator, (usually NUL, and that would imply modifying the string), or extra info must be returned, (eg. a length or an extra pointer to the end of the word, which is not allowed by 'just return a pointer'), or a different string must be returned, (forbidden by 'can't use memory allocation'), or an output string pointer could be supplied as a parameter, (forbidden by 'just return a pointer).  You have closed off all the approaches I know of:(

Comment: I suspect in the example given in the question, the desired return value is actually a pointer to the first char after the last blank char in the input string. This would mean, in the example given, that the return value would be `"dan!"` and not `"dan"`, which can be done with only a single pointer.

Comment: Then I guess the assignment itself is poorly defined.. How can I fix the code so it works like you've said Daniel?

Answer (score 0):

Compare the last character x of the last word you found in ASII, if it isn’t from “a” <= x <= “z” and “A” <= x <= “Z” then ‘delete’ it with your way

Comment: I think the easiest way to “delete” it is using ‘\0’ at the last (sorry if my English is bad, pls correct  if i’m wrong)

Answer (score 0):

> My question is how to return the last word

Read about [character classification functions in `<ctype.h>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte). You might want to use `isalpha`. However, [UTF8 is everywhere](http://utf8everywhere.org/), and things might be more complex (consider using [libunistring](https://www.gnu.org/software/libunistring/manual/libunistring.html))

You could return a fresh [heap-allocated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation) string (either use `calloc` to allocate it, then fill it appropriately but leave space for the terminating <kbd>NUL</kbd> byte; or use [`asprintf`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/asprintf.3.html) or [`strndup`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strndup.3.html) if you are allowed to use it) and document the convention that it should later be `free`-d (usually by the caller or later). Or you could return  a `struct` of two members, one being a pointer inside the input string and the other being the number of bytes of that word.